# manipulating list of list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

***so i wanted to manipulate a linked list that is in another list ;
this is the structure***

```
typedef struct liste_fav
{
       signed char numf[20];
       struct liste_fav *suiv;

}liste_fav;

    

/***********************************/

typedef struct abonnes
{
    signed char  num_c[20];
    signed  char operateur [20];
    signed char profil[20];
    int credit;
    liste_fav liste;
    struct abonnes *adr;
}abonnes;
```

***The problem is that i have a procedure that doesn't work, it compile but it returns everytime null, its function is to search the pointer that points to a specified number (num)***
***acces_num goes through the list until it finds the number we are searching or until the NULL , at the principle programme i'll check this by (if point==NULL then number not found )***

```
    liste_fav *acces_num(abonnes *p, signed char *num)
{
    liste_fav *point= &(p->liste);
    while ((point != NULL) && (numero_fav(point)!=num ))
    {
        point= suivant_fav(point);

    }
    return(point);
}
```

numero_fav : gives the number inside a an element of liste_fav
suivant_fav : gives the next element

```
  signed char * numero_fav( liste_fav *p)
{
    return (p ->numf);
}

    liste_fav *suivant_fav(liste_fav *p)
{
    return (p->suiv);
}
```

**could ypu tell me where is the error please!!**

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't work" means.  Does it mean it doesn't compile?  That it gives the wrong answer?  That it crashes when run?  That it never returns?

Comment: your `acces_num` function never actually checks for any particular number... it just keeps going through the list until it hits the end, and returns NULL (if the last node's `suiv` was NULL, at least)

Comment: you are right Dmitri , but how to solve it idk ?

Comment: in your while loop, compare the number in the node with the one you're checking for and if they match, return the pointer.  Since you're using strings for everything you'll probably want to convert both to numbers before comparing (for the `num` parameter, do it just once before entering the loop)

Comment: @Dmitri did u mean this :                        liste_fav *acces_num(abonnes *p, signed char *num)
{
    liste_fav *point= &(p->liste);
    while (point != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(num,numero_fav_propre(point))==0)
            return (point);
        else

            return NULL ;
 point=suivant_fav_propre(point);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code `numero_fav(point)!=num` looks like its trying to compare integers, not strings.  Both `num` and `numero_fav()` are character pointers, not integers.  [I'm assuming for the rest of this that they are supposed to be character strings that represent an ascii or similarly number). So both character pointers will functionally be different sections of memory and thus have different pointer values.

I think what you probably want is `strncmp(numero_fav(point), num, 20) != 0` for your test case instead.

Note that hard-coding `20` everywhere is probably accomplished with a define at the top too:

```
#define NUM_SIZE 20
...
signed char numf[NUM_SIZE];
```

for example.  And you need to watch out for what happens when someone tries to pass you a number string that is longer than 19 (your code doesn't show where the data comes from).